# Find the name and the city

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

Find the name and the city of my European friend using the following clues:

---

**Name**

1. Non-prime number.
2. Trussville, Alabama.

---

**City**

1. Prime number.
2. Clinton, Tennessee.

---

**Procedure to find the name and the city**

1. Seven-segment display.
2. Alternate dimension in 'Stranger Things'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your European friend is named...

> **ELISE**, and she lives in **LILLE** (France).

Finding the name:

> We're looking for a non-prime number associated with Trussville in Alabama. What numbers are usually associated with towns? Why their **ZIP code**, of course!
>
>  It turns out that the ZIP code for [Trussville, Alabama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trussville,_Alabama) is 35173. This is a composite number, being $17 * 2069$. If we write this on a seven-segment display and turn it [upside down](https://strangerthings.fandom.com/wiki/The_Upside_Down), we spell out **ELISE**:
>
>  [image: 35173 becomes ELISE when flipped]

Likewise, the city:

> The ZIP code for [Clinton, Tennessee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinton,_Tennessee) is 37717, a prime number this time. If we write this on a seven-segment display and turn it upside down, we spell out **LILLE**:
>
>  [image: 37717 becomes LILLE when flipped]